# Why does Lydia's Weapon glow?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I first got Lydia I immediately equipped her with the Axe of Whiterun. Since the axe is enchanted, when it glowed in her hand I thought nothing of it. I've recently given her an un-enchanted warhammer that out dps's the Axe of Whiterun. No biggy. Except the warhammer also glows in her hands. The glow is colored red, if that matters.

Lydia has no enchanted gear on her at all. Her weapon glows when she wields it. Why?

Comment: Might be a bug.. when you take it from her and equip it yourself, does it still glow?

Comment: never tried that, ill give it a go. i should mention that her bow (also unenchanted) glows too.

Comment: Maybe she is under some spell effect - did you cast something on her? Maybe used the console at some point?

Comment: I have never cast a spell on Lydia, not even a healing one. And I'm playing on the Xbox360 so the console is also a dead end. Wierd isnt it?

Comment: Weird indeed, no doubt. Did you do the College quests? They involve lots of magic. :)

Comment: I'm in the middle of the college quests now, but this glow has been going on since before I started them. /note, the glow continues. It wasn't a small period of time type of thing, its still going on.

Comment: Did you have the chance to take the weapon from her and try on yourself?

Comment: @Shadow: Yes, it does not glow. Nor do any of her non-enchanted weapons glow anymore. I cannot say anything other than perhaps it was a bug that lasted several days? God this game has entirely too many bugs.

Comment: Agreed, as for bugs it's expected in such a huge game.. in my opinion they done great job and they probably keep fixing bugs in the patches.

Comment: Not do dig up an ancient question from the dead or anything, but perhaps she had an ability that imbued her equipped weapon with some sort of magic?

Comment: @Nimphious digging up ancient questions is encouraged, and if you can name an ability, and source proof, then you've got somethin there.

Comment: Hmm, according to the wiki article (http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lydia) she has no magic abilities, but is able to use spell scrolls. If she is carrying one she might be using it, but since this has been happening for quite some time I'm sure she would have run out by now. Since she has no enchanted equipment, this is quite possibly a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is happening due to an enchanted item she is holding (necklace, ring, or something of the sort).

Comment: Wouldn't that make *her* glow but not her weapon glow?

Comment: would depend on the variation of the enchantment I believe.